# Is there a word or phrase that combines the meanings of 'inlet' and 'outlet'?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I wanted to tell a friend that I've discovered a new `social outlet`, but then I realized it was also an `inlet`. I was wondering if there's a word or phrase that combines those two meanings.

Something like `pipeline` perhaps? But `social pipeline` doesn't sound right.

Comment: Social network sounds like the most obvious answer to me. Networks are where information flows in and out, an inlet as well as an outlet.

Comment: In computer hardware terms they are called 'ports'.

Comment: In high level software architecture, e.g. Spring framework, they are called channels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps *channel*. The term has multiple meanings, several of which align with your concept. For example, *[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/channel)* offers, among others

> - a means of communication or expression: as (1) :  a path along which information (as data or music) in the form of an electrical signal passes (2) plural :  a fixed or official course of communication: *went through established military channels with his grievances*
> - a way, course, or direction of thought or action: *new channels of exploration*

The phrase *social channel* might work.

Comment: Saying "perhaps" would be an understatement. *Channel* is exactly the word used both in software engineering and social media. A simplex channel = one-way channel, either input/inlet or output/outlet. A duplex channel is a channel that allows inlet as well as outlet. A half-duplex channel is a channel that can function both ways, but only one way at a time, and has to be switched back and forth between inlet and outlet.

Comment: @BlessedGeek The *perhaps* is meant to indicate that I do not know the exact intent/point of view of the OP.